# prolog infinite loop unknown

Tags: prolog, infinite-loop

This is a program that receives a list of coordinates ex:[e(1,2,3),e(4,5,6)]. Making the dynamics, divide and conquer, separates the list in half
and half recursively,
when you have one transforms the coordinates in a tuple of values.
The problem is that it is in an infinite loop.

```
resuelve([X],D):-tuples([X],D).   
resuelve(Xs,D):-
     length(Xs,L), %length of the list
     divideIzq(Xs,L,Xa), %divide the left half
     divideDer(Xs,L,Xb), %divide the rigth half
     resuelve(Xa,D1), %left recursively
     resuelve(Xb,D2), %rigth recursively
     append_(D1,D2,D).    %concatenate tuples result

%function that transforms the coordinates
tuples([e(X,Y,Z)],D) :-  D = [c(X,Z),c(Y,0)].

divideIzq(Xs,L1,D):-
    L is div(L1, 2),
    take(L,Xs,D).


divideDer(Xs,L1,D):-  
    L is div(L1, 2),
    drop(L,Xs,D).

drop(0,LastElements,LastElements) :- !.
drop(N,[_|Tail],LastElements) :-
  N > 0,
  N1 is N  - 1,
  drop(N1,Tail,LastElements).


take(0, _, []) :- !.
take(N, [H|TA], [H|TB]) :-
  N > 0,
  N2 is N - 1,
  take(N2, TA, TB).

append_([], Cs, Cs).
append_([A|As],Bs,[A|Cs]):-
          append_(As, Bs, Cs).
```

Example:

```
% resuelve([e(3,6,5),e(4,9,3),e(8,11,2),e(10,12,4)], D).
% D = [c(3, 5), c(6, 0), c(4, 3), c(9, 0), c(8, 2), c(11, 0), c(10, 4), c(12, 0)]
```

Thanks

Comment: A lot going on here that's not visible (`divideIzq/3`? `divideDer/3`? `resuelveSkyline/2`?). Have you tried doing a `trace` to see how it loops?

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: Where is the recursion?

Comment: How are `take/3` and `drop/3` defined? What Prolog interpreter are you using?

Comment: If you do a trace on that goal, and press "U" (up) to get the first answer, then try a redo, you can see that there is a problem in `divideIzq([e(10, 12, 4)], _G1234)` It looks like this clause does not work correctly with just one element in the list...?

Answer (score 0):

Ready!

The problem is in the first line:

```
resuelve([X],D):-tuples([X],D) , !.
```

is necessary cut the tree.

Thanks for the help!